# Is it possible to draw basemap on many subplots without redrawing the map many times

Tags: python, multiprocessing, matplotlib-basemap

Normally when you create a basemap, you can assign it to an axes instance, for example

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot()
m = Basemap(..., ax=ax)
```

Now, if I want to make, say, 30 subplots, I need to do something like

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(6,5)
for ax in axes:
    m = Basemap(..., ax=ax)
    # plot some other things
```

But redrawing the basemap takes a long time. I was wondering whether it is possible to create the basemap instance once, and then assign it to all my axes. Something like:

```
m0 = Basemap(...) # without ax = ax
for ax in axes:
    m = add_basemap(ax,m0)
    # plot some other things
```

Is this possible?

As an alternative, I thought about creating the figure with all basemaps once and then pickling it, but the number of subplots is not always the same.

Comment: if you create one instance then you will have the same data on all maps.

Comment: hmm that's not what I need; the maps will be the same but the data will be different. Is it possible to duplicate the basemap then, instead of redrawing it?

Comment: as for me every basemap has to redraw on its own. I don't think it can create bitmap and then use bitmap instead of redrawing.

Answer (score 0):

If you plot on a `Basemap` in theory you can delete (or set invisible) all objects and reuse the map.

However I made two fuctions - one to generate a map and another to plot data:

```
def genMap():
    bMap = Basemap(llcrnrlat=5, urcrnrlat=50, llcrnrlon=10, urcrnrlon=210, \
     rsphere=(6378137.00,6356752.3142),resolution='i',projection='lcc',lat_1=30.,lat_2=60.,lat_0=48.,lon_0=135.)
    return bMap

def plot(cur_hour, leg, outdir, bMap, lon, lat):
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(17, 17), dpi=70, facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')
    bMap.drawcountries(linewidth=1.5, color='purple')
    bMap.fillcontinents(color='#FFFCC4', zorder = 0)
    bMap.drawcoastlines(linewidth=0.75)
    bMap.drawparallels(np.arange(-90., 120., 10.), labels=[1,0,0,0], color="k", fontsize=LEGEND_SIZE, linewidth=1, labelstyle='+/-')
    bMap.drawmeridians(np.arange(0., 420., 10.), labels=[0,0,0,1], color="k", fontsize=LEGEND_SIZE, linewidth=1, labelstyle='+/-')

    CF2 = plt.contourf(lon[::2,::2], lat[::2,::2], fl[::2,::2])
```

In main I call `genMap` once and use its result as a argument to my draw functions:

```
...
bMap = generateMap()
lon,lat = bMap(lon,lat)
t = threading.Thread(target=plot(cur_hour, leg, OUTDIR, bMap, lon, lat))
t.start()
...
t.join()
...
```

This code works very fast but I may be miss something in understating of Basemap class.

Answer (score 0):

It is actually possible to do this:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(6,5)
flat_axes = axes.reshape(-1)
m = Basemap(...) # without ax = ax
for ax in flat_axes:
    m.ax = ax
    # plot some other things
```

Note, that flattening axes grid is needed to make iteration easy. Still there might be a need to somehow reset the Basemap object instance after "plotting some other things" here.